# SQl Autobackup is not generating backup after sometime

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When i schedule the autobackup for a database it starts for that particular time, but after 1 day it's not generating any backup for the same database.

We don't have a DBA. I have also generated auto-backup on 2 APR, but after that no auto-backup was generated. I have deleted the plan & re-planned the Auto-backup process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you look at the SQL Server Agent job that was created for your maintenance plan... what does the schedule look like?  Or better yet, script out the job that is generated and post it here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the software SQL Autobackup? Because I think I'd go talk with their support first before coming onto StackOverflow.

Or are you talking about backups that can be taken via SQL Server maintenance plans?

Comment: I am talking about SQL Server's maintenance plan.

Comment: Based on the information, I'd check to make sure that it's a reoccurring job and that it's set to daily/weekly/you time schedule. Like mfredrickson said, it might be easiest if you can script the job to a new window and copy-paste the results here.